# how to display video through xslt

Tags: xslt, jquery-ui

How to show video through xslt? I have video library uploaded with few videos and description of it. I have to show description and respective video in jquery acccordian format on the page.

Comment: Well that would require some sort of plugin to render the video, either in say silver light or flash or some HTML 5 video tags. It is more up to you to find a plugin you like and then use xslt to render the markup needed for the specific plugin